# Only run coffeescript test for Node version 8 or greater

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, coffeescript

I have a CoffeeScript test which I only want to run if the Node version is 8 or greater. For any lower version number, I'd like to skip the test.

The file has the extension `.spec.coffee` and the test takes the following structure:

it.skip 'test name', ->

```
# __dirname is the 'test/' folder, so go up then find the SDK path
path = path.join __dirname, '..', 'folder1', 'folder2'

# run `npm run tstest`
exec = util.promisify(process.exec)
return exec 'npm run test', cwd: path
  .then (data) ->
    expect(data.stderr).to.eql ''
    expect(data.stdout).to.exist
```

As I understand it, `util.promisify` is not available in Node versions 7 or lower so I'd like this test to skip when running on these versions.

Is this possible and if so, how do I do it?

Comment: Apologies. Addiotional information has been added to the question.

Comment: As the answer suggests, promsify is polyfillable, and there's a polyfill, https://github.com/ljharb/util.promisify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get node's version inside a script with

```
process.versions.node
```

> As I understand it, util.promisify

instead of skipping the test, find a polyfill for that function.

Comment: Thanks. I've already got the polyfill. It'll just be a few weeks before it can go into production so I want to have something in place on my test until then I could skip the test completely but would prefer to run it against some versions if I can.